# Open LinkedIn app with sharing intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, linkedin-api, sharing

To force open Facebook,the following works:

```
public void shareFacebook() {
    String fullUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=..";
    try {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
                "com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your title text");
        startActivity(sharingIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(fullUrl));
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

How would this be done for LinkedIn?

Comment: you should not be explicitly hardcoding your intents. **This** is error prone. You should instead use the standard intents as provided by android that is extended by apps. Try reading http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html .

Comment: do you want to open linked in using android native share ?